# How to prove A inj B iff total injective function from A to B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that A inj B iff there is a total injective function from A to B.
This is what I have:
Suppose f: A -> B be injective.
Let x, y ∈ A be given.
Assume f(x)=f(y)
Therefore, x=y
Hence f is injective and R(x,y)

Now the other way round: 
If R ⊆ AxB then we have x ∈ A and y ∈ B so that xRy.
And I do not know how to continue with my proof. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure your terms are standard.  What does $A\,inj\,B$ mean?  How is it different from saying there is an injective function from $A\to B$?

Comment: A inj B as written in the exercise

Comment: Yes, I see that you used the expression in the exercise but it isn't clear (at least to me) what the expression means.  Can you include a clear and precise definition?

Comment: I will try: 
A (domain) and B (co-domain) are in an injective relation/function (one-to-one function), i.e. one element of the domain has its image in every element the codomain.

Comment: Not following.  You appear to just be saying that $A\,inj\,B$ if there is an injective function $f:A\to B$.  But as that is what the problem is asking you to prove  I assume there must be an independent definition.  Good luck.